# How to write a function that return maximum probability under the given array?

Tags: python, recursion

Give an array (2,2,2). I want to find a path to maximum to cross-product value.

I know I can list all of the possible paths, but the time and space complexity would be quite high the shape of the array is large.

Given an array mat, I want to max_prb function to calculate the following probabilities of paths and find the path with the greatest probability:

> - a->a->a = 0.2 * 0.5 = 0.01;
> - a->a->b = 0.2 * 0.5 = 0.01;
> - a->b->b = 0.8 * 0.9 = 0.72;
> - ...

My goal is to call max_prb_path and get [a,b,b]
For example:

```
mat = np.array([ [ [0.2, 0.8], [0.3, 0.7] ] ,[ [0.5, 0.5], [0.1, 0.9] ] ])
def max_prob_path(mat):
   return(path)

>> max_prob_path(mat)
[1] [a,b,b]
```

I think one of the solution would be recursive or BFS, but I am not familiar data structure or algorithm. Any suggestion? (Supposed the starting point is a but there is no ending point)

Comment: Do you have a start and an end or is it simply any shortest path (without a loop) through your multi-dim array. For example, say you had a 2x2x2x2 matrix and you started at [0,0,0,0] and wanted to get to [1,1,1,1] there would be 24 different (non-looping) paths to do this